# How to change variables in integrals of this sort

Tags: integration, change-of-variable

Consider an integral of the form:

$$\int f(u,v) dt$$

where $t=\dfrac{u+v}{2}$: how do I change variables in such a way to get an integral in $du$ and  $dv$ instead of $dt$?

This kind of integral came out in my work on general relativity: $t$ is coordinate time and $u$ and $v$ are retarded and advanced null coordinates.

Comment: Do partial derivative individually and add them up.

Comment: @cr001 So something like $\int f(u,v) \dfrac{dt}{du} du+\int f(u,v) \dfrac{dt}{dv} dv$?

Comment: That's correct.